# Moved docker dir to /home, /tmp directory error

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, containers

For reasons of space on / I have moved the directory / var / lib / docker to my home. Containers work fine, I can create new ones and manage everything as usual. But there is a problem with a framework, it gives me this error

```py
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 474, in mkstemp
    prefix, suffix, dir, output_type = _sanitize_params(prefix, suffix, dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 269, in _sanitize_params
    dir = gettempdir()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 435, in gettempdir
    tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 370, in _get_default_tempdir
    dirlist)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']
```

I checked inside the container and see the / tmp directory at 0%. I also tried changing directory permissions, but to no avail. I tried running
`docker-compose up --build`

Could you help me?

Docker ver:
`Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61`

Docker compose ver:
`docker-compose version 1.27.4, build unknown`

OS:
`Fedora 33`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added to my Dockerfile this

```
RUN chmod 777 -R /tmp && chmod o+t -R /tmp
```

Works!!

Answer (score 0):

Are those /tmp folders really temporary?

Make sure to use something like [mktemp](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/mktemp.html) to create the folders